# Como detectar una url en un texto y convertirla a un href

Tags: php

me esta fallando esta funcion que comprueba si en el texto hay una url para agregarle un href y asi si el usuario da click alli lo redireccione

```
function url($text)
{   
    $text=html_entity_decode($text);
    $text=" ".$text;
    $text=preg_replace('/(http(0,1):\/\/[\w\-\.\/#?&=]*)/','<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>',$text);
    return $text;
}


<div class="publi-contenido">
    <p><?php echo $posts['contenido']; ?></p>

static function agregar($CodUsua, $contenido, $img,$categoria)
{
    $textf=url($contenido);
    $con = conexion("root", "");
    $consulta = $con->prepare("insert into post(CodPost, CodUsua, contenido, img,categoria) values(null, :CodUsua, :contenido, :img, :categoria)");
    $consulta->execute(array(':CodUsua' => $CodUsua,
                             ':contenido' => $textf,
                             ':img' => $img,
                             ':categoria' => $categoria));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay casos que no están considerados en la expresión regular, como por ejemplo si empieza por https en lugar de http, o que no tenga www.

Te dejo aquí otra expresión que puedes probar:

```
"/(http|https)\:\/\/[a-zA-z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/"
```

Espero que te funcione. Este es el [origen](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/find-urls-in-text-make-links/).